# double scrollbar but no scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have the following css and html and it causes firefox (haven't checked other browsers) to show two scrollbars (2 right and 2 bottom) but they are seemingly disabled as even when minimised the page it does not scroll

```
    * {
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue','Helvetica','Arial';
    font-size:12px;
    color:#333;
}

html, body {
    background:#e0e0e0;
    height:100%;
    background-image: url('/images_/backgrounds/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;    
    margin:0;
    overflow: scroll;
}

/***************** main wrapper and content ********************/

#wrapper {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px auto;
    /*padding: 0px 12px 0px 12px;*/
    border:0;
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('/images_/backgrounds/content_shadow.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

#content { 
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding:85px 16px 10px 18px;
}

#topbar {
    width:100%;
    height:42px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background: #0066cc;
    /* make top bar stick to the top of browser */
    position:fixed;
    z-index:800;
    /*Making sure it sticks to left of window in IE7*/
    top:0;
    left:0;
    float:left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #666;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #666;
}

#top_blur {
    width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:70px;
    z-index:1;
    /*background-color: red;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
    position:fixed;
}

.header {
    width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    /*top: -70px;*/
    z-index: 801;
}
```

this is the html

```
<body><div id="wrapper">
<div id="topbar"></div>
<div id="top_blur"><img src=/images_/backgrounds/top_blur.png></div>
<div class="header"> header content here</div></div>
```

The

> overflow: scroll;

is there to force a scrollbar to fix the moving page bug that brosers have to stop whole page moving when scrollbar on vs off - i have tried setting this to auto but still no scrollbars when minimised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part here is because of those FIXED Positions from your DIVS.. thats why your scrolling has no effect.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Using :

```
overflow: scroll;
```

You'll force a scrollbar even if not needed.
Try putting :

```
overflow: auto;
```

which only show the bar when needed.

Comment: I tried that and the scrollbars did indeed go away but even minimised, still no scroll - will update question as forgot to mention that, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Aaarrrgh - I was missing a `"</div>"` @philip badilla prompted the recount!